# Sorting a table by the results of an array

Tags: php

In the table below, `$count1` is a numerical value.  How do I sort the table by `$count1` descending?

```
        $words = explode(" ", $commentstring);
        $result = array_combine($words, array_fill(0, count($words), 0));

        foreach($words as $word) {
        $result[$word]++;
        }


        echo "<table>";

        foreach($result as $word => $count1) {

        echo '<tr>';    
        echo '<td>';
        echo "$word";
        echo '</td>';

        echo '<td>';
        echo "$count1 ";
        echo '</td>';

        echo '</tr>';

        }

        echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`asort()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)?

Comment: use `asort()` for arranging in descending order and `arsort()` for ascending order

Comment: Where do I put the `asort()`?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `sort($array_var, SORT_DESC);`
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

EDIT:

Usage

```
$foo = array('bar', 'car', 'apple', 'food', 'banana');
sort($foo, SORT_DESC);
```

Answer (score 1):

After this line put `asort()`

```
 $words = explode(" ", $commentstring);
 asort($words);
```

Comment: This sorts the table rows by `$word` ascending.  I want to sort it by `$count1` descending.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the responders... they guided me in the right direction.  I finally got this to work:

```
foreach($words as $word) {
    $result[$word]++;

    arsort($result);

    }
```